# Can I use Supertokens with linkedin login oauth 2.0 as Third party provider ? How to do so?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, oauth-provider

I was researching about identity providers and I found supertokens (https://supertokens.com/docs/guides), it seems a nice solution but I would like to know if it also accepts LinkedIn as a third party provider because I couldn't see any info about this in docs or in any other related post. Also if you have any example code would be awesome

Find documentation about integration between supertokens and LinkedIn auth, couldn't find any.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for implementing custom providers is available here - https://supertokens.com/docs/thirdparty/common-customizations/sign-in-and-up/custom-providers. Based on that, here is a sample implementation for linkedin that you could use:

**Frontend:**

```js
export const SuperTokensConfig = {
    appInfo: {
        appName: "SuperTokens Demo App",
        apiDomain: "http://localhost:3001",
        websiteDomain: "http://localhost:3000",
    },
    // recipeList contains all the modules that you want to
    // use from SuperTokens. See the full list here: https://supertokens.com/docs/guides
    recipeList: [
        ThirdParty.init({
            signInAndUpFeature: {
                providers: [
                    {
                        id: "linkedin",
                        name: "Linkedin",

                        buttonComponent: <div style={{
                            cursor: "pointer",
                            border: "1",
                            paddingTop: "5px",
                            paddingBottom: "5px",
                            borderRadius: "5px",
                            borderStyle: "solid"
                        }}>Login with Linkedin</div>
                    }
                ],
            },
        }),
        Session.init(),
    ],
};
```

**Backend:**

```js
const Linkedin = (config: any): TypeProvider => {
    return {
        id: "linkedin",
        get: (redirectURI: string | undefined, authCodeFromRequest: string | undefined, userContext: any) => {
            const accessTokenParams: any = {
                client_id: config.clientId,
                client_secret: config.clientSecret,
                grant_type: "authorization_code",
            }
            if (redirectURI !== undefined) accessTokenParams["redirect_uri"] = redirectURI;
            if (authCodeFromRequest !== undefined) accessTokenParams["code"] = authCodeFromRequest;

            const authRedirectParams: any = {
                client_id: config.clientId,
                scope: "r_liteprofile r_emailaddress",
                response_type: "code",
            }
            if (redirectURI !== undefined) authRedirectParams["redirect_uri"] = redirectURI;

            return {
                accessTokenAPI: {
                    url: "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken",
                    params: accessTokenParams,
                },
                authorisationRedirect: {
                    url: "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization",
                    params: authRedirectParams,
                },
                getClientId: () => config.clientId,
                getProfileInfo: async (authCodeResponse: any, userContext: any) => {
                    const headers = {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${authCodeResponse.access_token}`,
                    }
                    const userInfo = (await axios.get("https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me", { headers })).data
                    const emailInfo = (await axios.get("https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))", { headers })).data
                    let email = ''
                    for (const element of emailInfo.elements) {
                        if (element['handle~'].emailAddress) {
                            email = element['handle~'].emailAddress
                            break
                        }
                    }
                    return {
                        id: userInfo.id,
                        email: {
                            id: email,
                            isVerified: false,
                        }
                    }
                },
            }
        },
    }
}

export const SuperTokensConfig: TypeInput = {
    supertokens: {
        connectionURI: "https://try.supertokens.com",
    },
    appInfo: {
        appName: "SuperTokens Demo App",
        apiDomain: "http://localhost:3001",
        websiteDomain: "http://localhost:3000",
    },
    recipeList: [
        ThirdParty.init({
            signInAndUpFeature: {
                providers: [
                    Linkedin({
                        clientId: "...",
                        clientSecret: "..."
                    }),
                ],
            },
        }),
        Session.init(),
    ],
};
```

If you are using python or the golang SDK, a similar implementation in that language should work.